# Contar celdas de un rango filtrado

Tags: excel, vba, macros

Estoy trabajando en unos reporte de Excel en los que se necesito la cantidad de tickets que no se están atendiendo (celdas vacias), según otros criterios.

Actualmente esto es lo que tengo en mi código

```
gsh.Shapes("UnpickedCE").TextFrame.Characters.Text = WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(sh.Range("I8:I" & k + 7))
```

Sin embargo, esto me cuenta todas las celdas que hay en el rango, sin el filtro aplicado, y si uso .specialCells

```
gsh.Shapes("UnpickedCE").TextFrame.Characters.Text = WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(sh.Range("I8:I" & k + 7).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible))
```

me arroja este error

> unable to get the countblank property of the worksheetfunction class

¿Alguna idea de como se pueda hacer ese conteo?

Answer (score 0):

```
gsh.Shapes("UnpickedCE").TextFrame.Characters.Text = WorksheetFunction.CountA(sh.Range("I8:I" & k + 7).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible))
```

Esto debería ayudarte. La función CountBlank cuenta las celdas en blanco y creo que no va a haber ninguna.

Debes utilizar un `CONTARA(COUNTA)` para que te cuente todas las celdas escritas, o un `CONTARSI(COUNTIF)` con el comodín del * para que coja cualquier celda escrita.

Comment: gracias, probaré con el COUNTIF ya que las celdas vacias son las unicas que debo de contar (ya edité la pregunta para añadir ese detalle)

Comment: Las celdas que están vacías, es porque tienen una fórmula que retorna blanco por X motivo, o están sin escribir totalmente?

Comment: estan sin escribir totalmente

Comment: ya probe con el COUNTIF (o más bien con el COUNTIFS) y funciono como un buen parche, aunque se necesita ser DEMASIADO especifico con los campos que se estan filtrando